# How to copy values from one row to another in the same table in PHPMyAdmin MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

**STEP 1**

We have a table called wp_postmeta with a meta_key being **video_url**

We have another meta_key value in the same table being **_heap_video_embed**

We want to copy all the values from the video_url field into the _heap_video_embed value, ensuring that the post_id values still correspond to the correct posts

**STEP 2**

The values in **video_url** are all youtube links e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHIhsLhQ-q8

However, once these have been copied into **heap_video_embed** we want to change this to use the youtube embed code also replacing everything before the **=** to **//www.youtube.com/embed/**

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="VIDEO_URL_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Sounds like a great plan... why not give it a shot? For additional reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649792/copy-rows-from-one-table-onto-another-using-insert-query

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the tick

```
UPDATE table_name SET _heap_video_embed=CONCAT('<iframe width="640" height="360" src="',REPLACE(video_url, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'),'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

changed

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHIhsLhQ-q8

into

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src=" http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZHIhsLhQ-q8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To be honest no idea where the extra space before the http came from and if this is exactly what you wanted or that the url should not have http infront but you should be able to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this, how about if we just want to do that in the video_url values? Without having to use _heap_video_embed

Comment: if you mean the complete embed code the same as above but then with _heap_video_embed replaced by video_url and if you mean just replace the url you can do UPDATE table_name SET video_url=REPLACE(video_url, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'); but i would do a test run or something first as it replaces your orignal data with no way back